# Why "SingleChildScrollView" Doesn't work around "AspectRatio" widget on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, overflow, aspect-ratio

This is my simple code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyMobileBody(),
    );
  }
}






class MyMobileBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMobileBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('M O B I L E'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // video section
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // comment section & recommended videos
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 8,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                        height: 120,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It gets the bottom overflow yellow/black error. I want to make the `AspectRatio` widget scrollable but using `SingleChildScrollView` didn't work. I also tried `ConstrainedBox` like below but it didn't work too:

```
      // comment section & recommended videos
      ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 8,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                  height: 120,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Add `shrinkWrap : true` to the ListView, then remove the `Expanded` widget that's wrapping the list view. Also add `mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min`. Then add SingleChildScrollView to the body of scaffold and the column inside it.

```dart
class MyMobileBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMobileBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('M O B I L E'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min,//<--here
              children: [
                // video section
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // comment section & recommended videos
//<--here removed expanded
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap:true,//<--here
                  itemCount: 8,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                        height: 120,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to keep the `AspectRatio` container in a fixed position and only scroll the `ListView` container?

Comment: Then remove the single child scroll view and shrink wrap true